# Running jQuery command from modal window to affect main page

Tags: php, jquery, window, modal-dialog

I'm currently trying to write a jQuery script which opens a modal box then (upon user entry) changes a value on the original page.

Currently I've got the script working on just the page itself (without the modal), but when I try to run the command from the modal the value on the main page doesn't change?

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: please edit your question and include the Javascript that is failing.

Comment: Is the modal using an iframe to show the content?

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in the page itself (not the modal sub-page), then call `opener.myMethod()` in the modal sub-page.

Comment: Hi,

So would something like this work:

 $('#select_socnet').click(function(){
  window.opener.$('#addnew').val('test');
  window.close();
 });

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the modal dialog is using an iframe, then from within the iframe you can do either of the following (depending on whether you have nested iframes or whatnot).

```
window.parent.myMethod();  
top.myMethod();
```

And to access elements on the main page you could do this (assuming you have jquery included on the main page as well):

```
top.$('#myDiv').html('hello world');
```

Hope this helps.